# Lisp -first elements of all list (superficial level)

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp

I'm new in Lisp and I'm trying to return the list of the first elements of all list elements of 
a given list with an odd number of elements at superficial level. 
Example: (1 2 (3 (4 5) (6 7)) 8 (9 10 11)) => (1 3 9).

This is what I've come up with:

```
(defun firstEl(L1)
  (cond
    ((null L1)   
           nil
    )
    ((LISTP (List L1))
          (firstEl (rest L1))
          (append (List L2) (first L1))
     )
    (t 
       (firstEl (rest L1) L2)
    )       
  )
)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please be more clear as to what your question is

Answer (score 1):

I often find functions such as [`mapcan`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mapc_.htm#mapcan) useful for recursive list processing:

```
(defun firstEl (value)
  ;;(print value)
  (if (listp value)
      (let ((first-value (first value))
            (tail (mapcan #'firstEl value)))
        (if (and (numberp first-value)
                 (oddp first-value))
            (cons first-value tail)
            tail))
      '()))
```

Comment: The number of elements should be odd, not the `car` itself.